# Two equivalent conditions of a strictly convex space.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Lindenstrauss defines in his paper that a Banach space $X$ is strictly convex if every boundary point of unit ball in $X$ is an exposed point. 
(A point of $B_X$(unit ball) is called an exposed point if there is $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x)>f(y) \forall y\neq x$ in $B_X$)

I already know that X is strictly convex if $\Vert x\Vert=\Vert y\Vert=1$ implies $\Vert x+y\Vert<2$, so they should be equivalent.

I can show the necessity : set $f(x)=\Vert x\Vert$ for $\Vert f\Vert=1$ and if $f(x)=f(y)$ that it violates the condition $\Vert x+y\Vert<2$.

But how to show sufficiency?

Comment: Your $f$ is not linear.

Comment: Such f exists by Hahn-Banach extension theorem

Comment: Of course. I think I have mistaken you and thought you define $f(x) = \|x\|$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: I wrote it ambiguously, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Both conditions are equivalent to: the unit sphere does not contain a nontrivial line segment.

Indeed, the existence of $x\ne y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=\|(x+y)/2\|=1$ means precisely that the line segment $[x,y]$ lies on the unit sphere.

If $[x,y]$ lies on the unit sphere, then $z=(x+y)/2$ is not exposed since $$f(z)=(f(x)+f(y))/2 \le \max(f(x), f(y))$$
Conversely, if $z$ is not exposed, then let $f$ be a norming functional for $z$ and observe that the set $\{x: \|x\|\le 1, f(x)=1 \}$ is convex, has more than one point, and lies on the unit sphere.

Comment: @Gerry It is intuitively clear from the diagram that if $x,y,x+y/2$ lie on the unit sphere, then the line segment $[x,y]$ lie on the unit sphere. However, how do I actually prove this rigorously?